# How to increase the thumnail size of nggallery carousel template

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

I want to increase the thumbnail image size of nggallery carousel template.
Check this link http://arkamediaworks.com/rel_test/uncatagorize/hello-2/?pid=6
is there any better code to do it. Here, is the code:

```
<!-- Thumbnail list -->
<?php foreach ( $images as $image ) : ?>
<?php if ( $image->hidden ) continue; ?>
<?php $subnavi[] = $image->pidlink ;?>
<li id="ngg-image-<?php echo $image->pid ?>" class="ngg-thumbnail-list <?php if ($image->pid == $current->pid) echo 'selected' ?>" >
    <a href="<?php echo $image->pidlink ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>"   />
    </a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you right, but this is how you can do it:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>"
alt="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>"
width="your_width_in_pixels"
height="your_height_in_pixels" />
```

If this is the anwer then it's not related to Wordpress but to HTML!
Have a nice day.